# Rails - Use fields_for to create multiple nested objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-forms, form-for, fields-for, nested-form-for

Hoping someone can help out with this. I have two models order and date_order. Each order can have multiple date_orders, and I should be able to create many date_orders as I create an order.

How do I do that? As you can see, my code is working well for creating ONE date_order and relating it to the created order.

UPDATE: I have tried to create many "builders" in my orders/new file. It worked on the view, and created an order when I entered multiple dates and times. But the fields_for did not create any date_orders.

orders_controller.rb

```
def new
    @order = Order.new
    @order.date_orders.build
end

def create
    @order = Order.new(order_params)
    if @order.save
        flash[:success] = "blah"
        redirect_to @order
    else
        render 'new'
    end
end

private

def order_params
    params.require(:order).permit(:user_id, :purpose, 
    date_orders_attributes: [:id, :order_date, :time_start, :time_end, :order_id])
end
```

order.rb

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base

     has_many :date_orders, :dependent => :destroy
     accepts_nested_attributes_for :date_orders, :reject_if => lambda { |a| a[:content].blank? }, :allow_destroy => true
end
```

date_order.rb

```
class DateOrder < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :order
end
```

order/new.html.erb

```
<%= form_for(@order, :html => {:multipart => true}) do |f| %>
    ## SOME QUESTIONS ##
    <%= f.fields_for :date_orders do |builder| %>
        <%= builder.label :date %>
        <%= builder.date_field :order_date %>

        <%= builder.label :starting_time %>
        <%= builder.time_field :time_start %>

        <%= builder.label :ending_time %>
        <%= builder.time_field :time_end %>

    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Build more `orders_dates`:

```
class OrdersController < ApplicationController
    def new
        @order = Order.new
        5.times { @order.date_orders.build }   # < === HERE ===
    end

    private

    def order_params
        params.require(:order).permit(:user_id, :purpose, 
        #                                 |-  === HERE ===
        date_orders_attributes: [:id, :content, :order_date, :time_start, :time_end, :order_id])
    end
end
```

#### Update:

Also, add `content` to your strong params whitelist.

Comment: This works on the view, but doesn't create any date_order objects.

Comment: That's because you have a validation that requires `date_order` to have `content` field, but you did not whitelisted it in your strong params. I'll update my answer to add that note as well.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Uzbekjon. You did solve my problem. Now, would you have any insight on having users create and remove date_orders? Say, you click a link to add a new one, or to remove a new one. Because the "5.times" is arbitrary, and users should determine the number of dates their order has.

Comment: You'd have to write javascript to achieve that. An easier option would be to use [`nested_form`](https://github.com/ryanb/nested_form) gem.